# Sequential XML filtering with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm trying to parse XML sequentially - the reason I'm not just looking for multiple attributes at one time is because some of the required attributes will require if statements, so I'm trying to set up for that. I tried the code below, but it didn't work - just returned a blank response (turned the content area blank with no filling). I know the rest of the code works because I've already tested it.

```
$.get('wallets.xml', function(data) {
    $('#content').empty();
    var $genders = $(data).find('wallet[gender=' + genderChosen + ']');
    $genders.find('wallet[material="leather"]').each(function() {
        var $wallet = $(this);
        printWallet($wallet);
    });
    });
}
```

Notice how I'm trying to filter the XML results by one attribute, then take those results and filter them by another attribute. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also note there are no errors in the console.

Comment: You should at least be getting a syntax error. You have mismatched parentheses.

Comment: The hanging close parentheses on the end is part of an if that I didn't display - is that what you're referring to? Cuz when I run the complete code I definitely don't get any errors, in Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the `find` method searches *descendants* of the collection you invoke it on. Seeing as both of your selectors use the tag name `wallet`, I suspect you meant to use `filter` the second time, which narrows down a collection by a selector expression:

```
$.get('wallets.xml', function(data) {
    $('#content').empty();
    var $genders = $(data).find('wallet[gender=' + genderChosen + ']');
    $genders.filter('wallet[material="leather"]').each(function() {
        var $wallet = $(this);
        printWallet($wallet);
    });
});
```

You also had a syntax error, which is corrected in the snippet above. Other possible sources of error might be that `printWallet` does nothing, or your XML is malformed.

Comment: This doesn't work either. I'm positive it's not another part of the code and the XML is valid because if I simply leave out the line beginning with $genders.find in my original code and start the .each from the line above it works fine.

Comment: @bmcswee have you considered that there may not be any `wallet` elements with that attribute value inside the first collection?

Comment: There most definitely are... feel free to look over my test page and XML file at http://ajaxtest.walletwallets.com/ajax10.php

Comment: I'm just guessing, but it looks to me like the $.parseXML is too early.. like maybe the variable $genders needs to passed to $.parseXML after the find statement? ..But I tried that and it didn't work either.

Comment: Still doesn't work - and still no errors in the console. Any other suggestions? See http://ajaxtest.walletwallets.com/ajax10.php for an example of the code you suggested in use.

Comment: @bmcswee Turns out the handler is passed a pre parsed document by jQuery. Just remove `$.parseXML(` from around `data`, while keeping the other changes, and it should work (I've tested this).